# php URL segment goes unexpected to index

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, slash

This is weird... I'm using the MVC pattern in php (codeigniter) to display a user's created categories. The URL pointing to a user's categories is

`http://mysite.com/categories/user`

This works in the Google Chrome browser but if Firefox it takes me to the index. Adding a trailing slash...

`http://mysite.com/categories/user/`

...takes me to the correct destination in both browsers. Also renaming the `user` controller works.

Inside controller

```
function user()
{
        $data['query'] = $this->Category_model->read_all_user_categories();
        $this->load->view('categories/read/user_categories', $data);    
}
```

The Model just returns a query.

What typically causes this behavior? I looked in all my files and can't find the culprit.

**Crossing out possible causes:**

- I don't have identical functions named `user`
- No Controller named `user`
- No library, helper named `user`

What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked CI's docs, and:

> The "index" function is always loaded by default if the second segment of the URI is empty.

Sorry for the mistaken information.

*The sentence below is still valid* (confirmation: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/links-to-wordpress-post-tabs-pages-must-have-trailing-slash)

The reason that it works on Chrome but not on Firefox, is due to Chrome's behavior of removing the last slash when submitting the request.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I see the benefit of using the last slash. I'm confused because renaming the `user` method works in both browsers slash or no slash

Comment: What do you mean? If you rename from `user` to, lets say, `banana` it works?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just corrected my answer, as the top bit was wrong. But still, the answer for "why it works on Chrome but no on FF" still valid. You should check your `routes.php` file. This might help: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/94028/